# Why does an object become invisible if its index of refraction is equal to the index of refraction of the medium that contains it?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, thought-experiment

If we suppose that we can change the refractive index of an object to be equal to the refractive index of its surrounding so that it becomes invisible, how can we explain this process?

Comment: It wouldn't be invisible if the colour were different...

Comment: What colour you are referring?

Comment: If the object has any colour that's different from the surrounding liquid, you will still see it.

Answer (score 1):

In an homogeneous lossless medium the EM (light) wave propagates unimpeded. Our eyes see an object by having the light rays reflected off the surface of the object, and when the reflected rays reach our eyes they get focused on the retina. If the light rays do not reflect off the surface of an object into our eyes then we do not see *it*. If the object has the same refractive index as its surroundings then there is no reflection off the surface, hence nothing to see. If the object is absorbing but its refractive index is the same as that of the embedding medium we can *see* the object's shadow by noticing the intensity difference between of light going through the object and passing by but outside the object.

Comment: Isn't it better to say that "If the object has the same refractive index as its surroundings then there is no REFRACTION..."? Or are they just the same?

Comment: To get reflection you need a change in the refractive index; the EEs call it impedance mismatch. You will learn about this subject in EM under the heading "transmission lines", the theory is essentially the same in optics and use similar terminology when discussing glass coating to reduce reflection. You can have an ideal perfect defined as $n \to \infty$ and then there is no penetration into the material hence no refraction but otherwise partial reflection comes with partial refraction, the two are inseparable, just as no diffraction without interference, no interference without diffraction..